# JSoup Attempts to Connect to wrong URL

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to connect to a URL in an `AsynTask` but am having trouble.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gasbuddy.com/home?search=33444&fuel=1").get();
```

gives me an error in my log saying:

> Error Connecting: failed to connect to www.gasbuddy.com/104.17.148.191 (port 443) after 30000ms

After doing some research, I believe I need to connect to the baseURL. However, I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried:

```
URL absoluteUrl = new URL(new URL("https://www.gasbuddy.com/home?search=33444&fuel=1"), "script.js");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(absoluteUrl)).get();
```

But I get the same error in my my logs.

Edit: I get the same error on any website I try connecting too ("https://www.yahoo.com/", "https://www.google.com/", etc) I'm on a a public Starbucks Wifi at the moment, not sure if that matters.

Comment: `yahoo` and `google` works fine for me, so maybe there's a firewall or something blocking your requests. But `gasbuddy` throws error 403, it is expecting some cookies to be setted. It seems that they are actively trying to block bots/automatic requests.

Comment: @LorisSecuro interesting, so do you think being on a public Wifi is messing up my attempt to connect to google and yahoo? I'm going to try again on my WiFi when I get home.

Comment: possibly... I don't have other ideas

Comment: @LorisSecuro I fixed the problem by removing the 's' in https. `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gasbuddy.com/home?search=33444&fuel=1").get();`